# AJAX: How to use returned array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, model-view-controller

I have an ajax POST that sends data to a controller function and that function returns a string array back to the ajax call as the default 1st parameter in the ajax success method. When I tried to use the returned data, it won't let me print the 1st element to an alert box. How come?

i.e.

```
 $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Home/stringSplitFunct",
            data: { 'parameter1': Input },
            success: function (response) 
            {
                alert(response[0]);                  
            }
        });
```

In fact, I don't think it even recognize it as a string array.

Comment: Are you making it into the success method? What is actually in response when the ajax returns?

Comment: Try using an actual debug tool, like the console, and do `console.log(response)` and then post what you get.

Comment: Or check in chrome what was sent to and from the server (Network tab).

Comment: try to use 


success: function (response) 
            {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(response[0]);                  
            }

Comment: You have to return a JSON object from your controller.
return Json(yourStringArray, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

Comment: Okay, I should use JSON to pass arrays and other complex data types. And Francis... best edit ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `dataType`. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Home/stringSplitFunct",
            data: { 'parameter1': Input },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) 
            {
                alert(response[0]);                  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not only changing the data type, but i also have to make sure to return a JSON object as well and parse it into a JavaScript object using eval()

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data is being returned as a raw sting.

Use `dataType` property for your ajax request

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Also avoid using alert as it stops the execution flow. Use `console.log` instead

Comment: I imagine the alert is just for quick and dirty troubleshooting. And console has its own pitfalls; for example, if a page tries to use console in IE with the developer tools not open, it generates a javascript error and terminates the script.